# Data structure for a sum of numbers that keeps the balance updated

Tags: database, data-structures, sum, aggregate, b-tree

I have a table with millions of transactions of a single account. Each transaction contains:

- `moment` - Timestamp when the transaction happened.
- `sequence` - A number to sort transactions that happen at exact same `moment`.
- `description`, `merchant`, etc - overall information.
- `amount` - The monetary value of the transaction, which may be positive or negative.
- `balance` - The account balance after the transaction (sum of current and all previous `amount`). This is computed by the system.

What data structure is optimized for quickly displaying or updating the correct `balance` of all transactions, assuming the user can insert, delete or modify the `amount` of very old transactions?

My current option is organizing the transactions in a [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) of order *M*, then store the sum of `amount` on each node. Then if some very old transaction is updated, I only update the corresponding node sum and all its parents up the root, which is very fast. It also allows me to show the total `balance` with a single read of the root node. However in order to display the right `balance` value of future records, I eventually need to read *M* nodes, which is kind of slow assuming each node is on cloud storage.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Solution with B-tree may be enhanced further. You may store a list of delta modifications in RAM. This list (which also may be a binary tree) contains only updates and is sorted by timestamp.

For example, this list may look like following at some point:

(t<sub>1</sub>, +5), (t<sub>10</sub>, -6), (t<sub>15</sub>, +80)

This means that when you need to display balance of transaction with timestamp

- less than t<sub>1</sub> - do nothing
- between [t<sub>1</sub>, t<sub>10</sub>) - you add 5
- between [t<sub>10</sub>, t<sub>15</sub>) - decrement by 6
- [t<sub>15</sub>, inf) - add 80

Now suppose that we need to make modification (t<sub>2</sub>, -3). We

1. Insert this node into list at proper position
2. Update all nodes to the right with delta (-3)
3. Update this node`s value with value from its left neighbor (+5 -3 = +2)

List becomes:

(t<sub>1</sub>, +5), (t<sub>2</sub>, +2), (t<sub>10</sub>, -9), (t<sub>15</sub>, +77)

Eventually, when delta list becomes large, you will need to apply it to your B-tree.